# How to create an war file in Eclipse without ant or maven?

Tags: eclipse, servlets, war

I am using *Eclipse IDE for Java Developers* Helios. I have mainly done desktop applications before but now I would like to learn about Servlets. I have installed Jetty on my computer. And I wrote a simple Servlet in Java using Eclipse. But how do I compile it and export it to a war file in Eclipse? I have found some tutorials doing it with Ant, but I would like to do it native in Eclipse if possible.

Here is my Servlet:

```
package org.jonas;

// some imports from java.io, java.servlet and java.servlet.http

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String name = request.getParameter("name");

        out.println(
                "<html><body>" +
                "<h1>" + name + "</h1>" +
                "</body></html>");
    }
}
```

How can I compile it and export it as a war file in Eclipse? Without Ant or Maven. So I can deploy it in Jetty.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Edit:** As @nos has inferred, the OP was using "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" and not "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers". The below is only relevant for the latter.

Assuming you created this as a **Dynamic Web project** in Eclipse, just

right-click on the

```
project name, > Export > WAR file
```

and fill in the details it asks for.

If you didnt create this as Dynamic Web Project, [you can convert your static web project](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/twpcnvrt.html) into one first

Comment: I don't have a *Dynamic Web project* alternative. In the *New Project* dialog, I just have *Java Project* and *Java Project from Existing Ant Buildfile* under the Java directory.

Comment: @Jonas Sounds like you have "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" and not "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" , the latter has more support for creating Servlets/JSPs.

Comment: @nos: True, is it possible to upgrade via plugins? I use my Eclipse for many other things that already is installed.

Comment: @Jonas: Regarding upgrade via plugins. Not that I know of - you'd have to download the "Java EE" version and then import your old projects into new installation.

Comment: I thought that Eclipse was a flexible IDE where I could just add new plugins if I needed. But that was wrong, I have to download a hole new Eclipse for some things :( I have downloaded the *Java EE* edition now. But it doesn't seem possible to convert my *Java Project* to a *Dynamic Web Project* so I have to create a new *Dynamic Web Project*. I choosed `New Servlet` and surprisingly the generated code has errors on `@WebServlet("/MyServlet")` but I will work on this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Jonas: But see, the support is better for Java EE, else this would fail in your server and would be more painful to debug ;)

Comment: You **can** add the necessary software, instead of downloading Eclipse's Java EE edition from scratch.  I know it's too late for you Jonas, but future readers might benefit.  Just install the "Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools" package from Eclipse's update site.