# How to create war file in eclipse with all the necessary dependencies without maven or ant

Tags: java, eclipse, export, war

I saw lots of questions including this one : [How to create an war file in Eclipse without ant or maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032421/how-to-create-an-war-file-in-eclipse-without-ant-or-maven)

I have standard web project created with eclipse. In this web project like many others there isn't only jsp and web files, but java files also. I am using eclipse Luna and I am trying to export my project as war but when I use the export option and package it like war it packages only my web content. Normally after I deploy it to tomcat it fails on login in my site because there is no java files on the war. I am new to the web projects and I do not want to use maven or ant. I want to just simply make working war from eclipse and could not find normal way to do that.

Comment: Make sure your java files are on the build path?

Comment: hah my java files are in my project's src directory - absolutely normal. When I use eclipse all is ok and my project runs. Just eclipse package only my webcontent - extremley strange how someone could make such war. Who need only web contends without the java ....

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on your Web project --> export --> War file --> Choose destination path and select on Export source files.

See the below screen shot:

[image]

After creating Excel2DB22.war. I have imported it again into my IDE. I can see all the files including java also in that project.
See the below SS:

[image]

I hope it will help you.

Comment: no. I tried that but the result is the same - only the web content! no java files

Comment: now I found my classes in the war but in another directory \WEB-INF\classes\. And the reason my website does not work is they are moved and the classes is not found. I need them in /src not in \WEB-INF\classes\ ... Why eclipse do that?

Comment: Placing compiled classes in the `/WEB-INF/classes` folder is the only way a Java Servlet container (such as Jetty or Tomcat) will use them; that's the standard layout for a WAR. What server are you trying to deploy/run your application in?

Comment: @dimilalabar: Also, you should update your question with the information in your last comment above - that information is material to the question (actually, to your misunderstanding of what you're supposed to get when you build a WAR).